# How to calculate RSSI empirically?

Tags: power, signal

can we calculate RSSI? is RSSI and power received are same?

From research papers i found this

```
PL(d; n; o) = PL(d0) + 10nlog10(d/d0) + Xo
RSSI=Pt-PL(d).
```

but on the other hand some papers calculate this RSSI just like this PL.as shown below:

```
RSSI=A−10nlog(d/d0)−Xσ. 

RSSĪ  is regarded as RSSI value of multiple times of measurement.

RSSĪ =A−10nlog(d).
```

i am confused.
what i should use?

Comment: RSSI stands for *Received* Signal Strength Indicator, not Relative.

Comment: who said relative?

Comment: Someone who deleted their comment lol